# Visual studio MVC razor view intelisens and breakpoints not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-3

I am using visual studio 2012 (Premium). I have a project that is using MVC. I am not able to add any breakpoint to the view(s) and thus unable to debug the variables at view side. 
Moreover, Intelisens is also not working at views.

What I have tried:

I tried resetting the user setting devenv.exe/resetusersetting.
Tried clear the cache using below command:
Hide   Copy Code
C:\Users\pgoel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

I also tried many other things I came cross while looking for the solution but nothing works. Please help me out to get it fixed.

Comment: have you tried restarting visual studio?

Comment: Close VS and open again. Bdw if your view is strongly typed then only you can debug, otherwise you can't.

Comment: I tried that. In-fact I have another project which is having similar strongly types model/views. There the MVC View debugging is working fine. Closing and reopening, Cleaning cache does nothing.

Comment: @jamiedanq This is first step I performed. Nothing positive.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time looking for solution, I come across that for MVC projects, the version of MVC I am using should be installed in the environment. Although if I have added the dll but not installed in environment, the project will work but intellisense won't work.

Here is the fix. Go to web.config.

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
```

See the version of MVC you are using and run the following Nuget command to install it.

```
PM > Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
```

Version should be the same as mentioned in you web.config or MVC dll you are using.

[See link for more information](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc)